# English Names of the Five Chumashim

Tags: history, names, pentateuch-chumash, english

The Hebrew names of the Chumashim are usually referred to as בראשית  שמות  ויקרא etc. but the English names do not correlate with these names literally. The English names are Exodus, Numbers etc not Names, Desert (or Wilderness). While the Hebrew names are obviously based on the first words (or Parsha) of the sefer, where did the other names originate from and why don't we just use the English translation of the Hebrew version?

Comment: These English words are taken from the book titles in the Septuagint, so that might be a place to start in terms of reasearch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MY! These are non-Jewish names taken from Greek, so I don't know to what extent your question is on-topic here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah#Contents

Comment: My original question was more as to why the Engligh translations use those names as opposed to the Hebrew names. It was edited by someone to remove that part of the question. I added it back in

Comment: "why don't we just use the English translation of the Hebrew version" I don't understand the question. Use whatever you want. People speaking English usually use English words.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a reason all the translations use this vs that.

Comment: Translations to English use English. What's the question?

Comment: They are translating the Greek version vs the Hebrew version. Is there a reason or source for that?

Comment: @Chatzkel Most English-speaking folks were/are Christians, so why do you expect them to use Jewish names instead of what their church gave them?

Comment: I don't mean here. Artscroll and all other publishers use them as well.

Comment: Why did you say "Hebrew" instead of "Holy Tongue"?

Comment: Also, in your example you translate the meaningful ones, but could you imagine yourself saying "in the book _In the beginning_ or _Called_ or _Words?"_ Jews didn't really use titles in ancient times as Greeks and Romans did, so Christians needed meaningful ones to fit their culture.

Comment: True. Didn't think of that. Good point

Comment: Art Scroll etc use the English terms so that the nonJews will understand what is meant just as we use the chapter numbers created by the church when speaking in terms they will understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in midrash and other early sources, you will actually find the following Hebrew names for the 5 books:

1. Sefer Bereshit
2. Sefer Hageulah
3. Toras Kohanim
4. Chumash Hapekudim
5. Mishneh Torah

These ancient Hebrew names correspond exactly with the English names you cited. For some reason, in modern Jewish speech the names based on the first word have become more popular. However, the names in English, deriving from the Septuagint, possibly originated from these ancient Hebrew names of these books.

Comment: Wikipedia says that the Septuagint was created around the 3rd century BC. Most of our midrashim come from a far later period, often centuries later. Why do you think that we invented these names and not heard them from the Hellenised Jews?

Comment: @Kazibácsi that is a fair comment. Perhaps you are correct. My main point was that the older Hebrew names did indeed correspond with these names. As to which came first, I guess that is speculation and impossible to know. I find it unlikely that jews did not have names for these books, but I guess which came first is lost to history. I changed my answer from probably to possibly.

Comment: Titles were later invented in antiquity, initially such works didn't have proper titles. See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_(publishing)

Comment: @Kazibácsi that article does not seem particularly well sourced or convincing. There are several books, with titles, quoted by name within Tanakh itself.

Comment: @chess like what? ספר דברי הימים למלכי יהודה is a description not a title.

Comment: @DoubleAA Milchamot Hashem and Sefer Hayashar were the ones I thought of. Here is a whole list of them. Apparently there are a few more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-canonical_books_referenced_in_the_Bible

Comment: @chess sefer milchamot hashem is also not a title but a description. None of us have a clue what sefer hayashar is to know if it's a proper title.

Comment: @chessprogrammer Here's one cited work there, turn to page 2: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3724776

Comment: @DoubleAA your distinction between title and description seems a bit arbitrary to me. By the same token, you could say Mishnah Torah or sefer geula or toras kohanim is a description not a title. I don't really see any distinction between these names and Milchamot Hashem. Care to elaborate?

Comment: The relevant distinction is just that formal titles didn't exist back then and you have no proof otherwise from Tanach. See Kazi's link. This whole thread is about identifying proper titles and their history, so this distinction seems most central

Comment: @DoubleAA understood. All I am saying is that names such as Toras Kohnim could have existed back then as well, as long as you view it as a description not title. In other words what I am saying is that this article does not tell me people in days of old did not use some term for the books of chumash, even if you preffer to call the term they use a description and not a title.

Comment: @chess only they wouldn't have been names, but descriptions. It's like asking you to pass the blue bottle vs the Blue Bottle. The former is ad hoc description of some bottle, the latter is a name for a specific kind of wine. People didn't have names for works generally but rather just described whatever they wanted as needed. It's different from how we're used to thinking so it's hard to get your head around

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand that. But at whatever point in history when these books were  named, the names probably were  not created in a vacuum but evolved in some form from existing descriptions. Which is why I find it plausuble that the septuigint names originated from some sort of a Hebrew precedent.

Comment: All I am disputing is the claim that this article implies these names cannot have originated in Hebrew.